# Why can't I access my local Gatsby site on my phone

Tags: windows-10, localhost, gatsby, development-environment

I am new to Gatsby, and I will be starting my first project today. I want to be able to test the site on my android phone to ensure mobile compatibility rather than using chrome dev-tools.

I have only ran a few commands so far.

1) `Gatsby new site-name`

2) `cd site-name`

3) `gatsby develop --host 0.0.0.0 -p 8080`

Everything compiles properly, and I can access the default Gatsby page through localhost:8080 or 192.168.1.81:8080 on the host laptop, but when i attempt to access from my android phone, it says that the server is unreachable. I am running windows 10 on my laptop, and so far Ive checked the firewall, and I've tried a few different ports as well. If someone has dealt with this issue and could help me that would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 29):

They blocked access by default but you can access it by adding `-H 0.0.0.0` to develop command. For example change your package.json to:

```
"develop": "gatsby develop -H 0.0.0.0",
```

Answer (score 12):

you can fix this issue by using this command

```
gatsby develop -H 0.0.0.0
```

more information : [from here](https://dev.to/konyu/how-to-check-the-operation-of-gatsby-on-a-smartphone-or-other-device-that-is-under-development-in-a-local-network-2jmb)

after you can use your pc ip address with the port number to debug gatsby site on your mobile

Example :

> 192.168.1.4:8000

Answer (score 1):

I had to do:

```bash
gatsby develop -h 192.168.xx.xx -p 8080
```

Answer (score 0):

Your phone and and the computer you are running from needs to be on same wifi/network. I need sometimes to reconnect my phone to the wifi to get it right. Suppose it has to do with the private ip adress the router is assigning to devices.

Then `192.168.1.xx:8000` can be opened on phone browser.

Comment: You'd think so, but no. Also the local address is more likely to be `10.0.0.x:8000`